# Perform an orderBy in my breeze query don't work in my case

Tags: breeze

I use breezejs in my Durandal web application.

Here is my code to get my invoice & lines behind it:

```
var getInvoiceById = function (invoiceId, invoiceObservable, forceRemote) {
    // Input: invoiceId: the id of the invoice to retrieve
    // Input: forceRemote: boolean to force the fetch from server
    // Output: invoiceObservable: an observable filled with the invoice

    if (forceRemote)
        queryCacheInvoice = {};

    var query = entityQuery.from('Invoices')
        .where('id', '==', invoiceId)
        .expand("Client, Client.Contacts, Lines")
        .orderBy('Lines.Number');

    var isInCache = queryCacheInvoice[invoiceId];

    if (isInCache && !forceRemote) {
        query = query.using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache);
    } else {
        queryCacheInvoice[invoiceId] = true;
        query = query.using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromServer);
    }

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        invoiceObservable(data.results[0]);
    }
};
```

And here is the models for Invoice:

```
public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public double? TotalExclVAT { get; set; }        
    public double? TotalInclVAT { get; set; }
    public double? TotalVAT { get; set; }
    public bool? WithoutVAT { get; set; }

    public virtual List<InvoiceLine> Lines { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Please notice that for each invoice I have many invoice lines:

`public virtual List<InvoiceLine> Lines { get; set; }`

And here is the models for InvoiceLine:

```
public class InvoiceLine
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

**The problem**: when I execute this breeze query I got the error below:

**Error retreiving data. unable to locate property: Lines on type: Invoice**

The problem is around the orderBy clause. I have a 1-to-many relationship between the Invoice and the InvoiceLine so it seems I cannot perform an order by in this case.

**My question**: how to proceed to be able to sort my lines of invoice by number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **You can't.** This is a limitation of Entity Framework, not Breeze.

You cannot filter, select, or order the related entities that you include with "expand" in an EF LINQ query.

You will probably manage the sort order of related entities on the client, e.g., the display of your order line items.

Note also that the collection of entities returned by a Breeze navigation path is unordered. I wasn't sure what happens if you tried to sort a Breeze entity navigation collection (e.g., Order.LineItems). I was afraid that would cause Breeze to think that you had made changes to the entities ... because a sort would seem to remove-and-add entities to the collection as it sorted. Your `EntityManager` would think there were changes pending when, in fact, nothing of substance has changed.

I tried an experiment and it all seems to work fine. I did something like this with Northwind:

- fetched the Orders of a Customer ("Let's Stop N Shop")
- checked the sequence of `cust.Orders()`; they have unordered OrderIDs: [10719, 10735, 10884, 10579]
- executed a line like this: `cust.Orders().sort(function(left, right){return left.OrderID() < right.OrderID()? -1 : 1})`
- checked the sequence of `cust.Orders()` again; this time they are sorted: [10579, 10719, 10735, 10884]
- checked the customer's `EntityManager.hasChanges()` ... still false (no changes).

I confess that I am happily surprised. I need to write a proper test to ensure that this works reliably. And I have to make sure that the Knockout binding to the navigation property displays them in the sorted order. But I'm encouraged so far.

> **Important Notes**:
>
> 1. Breeze won't keep the list sorted. You'll have to do that if you add new orders or if Breeze adds new orders to the collection as a result of subsequent queries.
> 2. Your sort affects *every view* that is bound to this navigation property. If you want each view to have its own sort of the entities in that collection, you'll have to maintain separate, view-specific collections that shadow the navigation property collection.

If I am wrong about all of this, you'll have to manage a shadow collection of the related entities, sorted as you wish, for each ViewModel.

### Update 2 June

I suspected that we would have to let KO know about the array change after sort by calling `valueHasMutated`. I took 15 minutes for an experiment. And it seems to work fine.

I created a new KO Todo app from the ASP.NET SPA template (there's currently a phantom complaint about a missing jQuery.UI library which is totally unnecessary anyway).

I added a "sort link" to the *index.cshtml* just above the delete-TodoList link:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.sortList">Sort</a>
```

Then I implemented it in *viewModel.js*:

```
var sortAscending = true;
var viewmodel = {
    ...
    sortList: sortList,
    ...
};
...
function sortList(list) {
    list.todos().sort(function(left, right) {
        return (sortAscending ? 1 : -1) *
            (left.title().toLowerCase() < right.title().toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);
    });
    sortAscending = !sortAscending; // reverse sort direction
    list.todos.valueHasMutated();   // let KO know that we've sorted
}
```

Works like a charm. Sorting, adding, deleting Todos at will. The app is saving when expected as I add and delete ... but not during save.

Give `valueHasMutated` a try.

Comment: I was not aware about the limitation of Entity Framework about that. I try as you suggested by performing a sort on the UI something like this `cust.Orders().sort(function(left, right){return left.OrderID() < right.OrderID()? -1 : 1})`. The sort is effectively performed that's a good poing BUT there is another problem that appeared: before I was able to add/remove elements of my nested entity and immediately having the UI reflected my action (showing/hiding the added/removed element). (continue on next comment)...

Comment: ... With the sort performed the UI is no more refreshed. For example, when deleting an element (invoice line)  from my nested entity, my UI didn't remove the element from my foreach on my observableArray. By removing the sort (only 1 line of code) it is working again as before. Do you noticed that problem? Any idea to have the sort working on nested entity WITHOUT break functionalities? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thanks for your update. When I inject `invoice.lines.valueHasMutated();` in my code on the line below my sort I got the error: Error retreiving data. Cannot call method 'valueHasMutated' of undefined. Then I proceed like that: `if (invoice && invoice.lines) invoice.lines.valueHasMutated();` but I still has the problem explained in my previous comment.

Comment: The error message tells you what you need to know: you do not have the data. You have a timing problem. No point in adding that "if" test; all it does is keep the `valueHasMutated` from executing; you have to call `valueHasMutated` to get KO to listen and update the UI. I cannot explain your experience without the actual code. I've told you how to create my sample - it should take you 15 minutes. I suggest that you start there and compare with your code to see what is different. Good luck

Comment: I got it working: I need to reference my invoice.lines from my viewModel variable like this: `vm.invoice().lines.valueHasMutated();`. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Excellent. I assume you're calling `valueHasMutated` only after a sort.

Comment: To respond to your question: yes only after a sort. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Ward been struggling with ordering an expanded entity for the whole day. Even valieHasMutaded gives undefined. Anyways, I got it fixed by sorting right before filling the observable with data. i.e. data.results.sort then observable(data.results) without having to use valieHasMutaded .. Honestly, I'm really admired of your trying hard to help the community. Thank you.